# How to Binding data to User Control loaded in Control Template?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

My CMainViewModel has a property called AnalogGaugeValue1

On my Window I have a data template as shown below.  I use this template to load a user control named AnalogIOView and try to binding the dependency property, GaugeValue1DP, inside AnalogIOView to the AnalogGaugeValue1

```
<Window>

  <Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="AnalogIOViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:CMainViewModel}">
        <local:AnalogIOView 
               GaugeValue1DP="{Binding Path=AnalogGaugeValue1}"   />
   </DataTemplate>

  </Window.Resources>

<Window>
```

I use the ContentControl to load the AnalogIOViewTemplate in my Window as shown below

```
<Grid>

                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value=" 
                                    {StaticResource AnalogIOViewTemplate }" />
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>

</Grid>
```

The user control displays correctly on my Window but I could not set the Analog Gauge value through binding in CMainViewModel.

However, If I just load the user control directly (without using Control Template) then it is working correctly as shown below

```
<Grid>
   <local:AnalogIOView GaugeValue1DP="{Binding Path=AnalogGaugeValue1}" />
</Grid>
```

My question is why it does not work when loading the user control using Content Control template and data template

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you set the Content property of the ContentControl somewhere? Otherwise it would be pointless to use it.

Comment: As a note, if you would not set `x:Key` on the DataTemplate, you could save the whole ContentControl Style, because you would not need to set the ContentTemplate explicitly. All you need would be `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>`.

Comment: Clemens: Not using elsewhere

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you understand that you have to set the Content?

Comment: It is working now.
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                <ContentControl.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource 
      AnalogIOViewTemplate }" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentControl.Style>
                            </ContentControl>

Thanks Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `Content` property, and it would also be simpler not set an `x:Key` on the DataTemplate. It would then automatically be selected as the ContentTemplate of the ContentControl.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CMainViewModel}">
            <local:AnalogIOView GaugeValue1DP="{Binding AnalogGaugeValue1}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
<Window>
```

Comment: I need to load more than one user control on my Windows and possible dynamically based on current selection of menu item.  Thanks